# Removing duplicate values from nested JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, duplicates

I'm currently rendering a list of `Labels` (see JSON snippet) from a local JSON file. However, there are [duplicates of them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nX6fm.png) and I want to have each one show up once. I tried to implement `Array.filter()` and a few other methods to get this line: `"Categories": obj.ResourceType.results.map(function(val) { return val.Label;`, but something about my syntax was pretty wonky so nothing rendered.

Any ideas? Ideally I want to use something to replace this part of the code:

```
distinctArray(inp) {
  let uniqueArr = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
    if(inp[i] == undefined) continue;
    if(uniqueArr.indexOf(inp[i]) < 0) {
      uniqueArr.push(inp[i]);
    }
  }
return uniqueArr;
}
```

, while still working with this section that's above it:

```
let categories = this.distinctArray(temp).sort();

$("#km-labels").html(categories.join("<br>"));
```

---

#### JS snippet:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

import JSONfile from '../../../public/JSONfile.json';
import { basename } from 'path';

var categories = '';

export default class {
    constructor() {
        this.loadData();
    }

// ------------------------------------ //

    loadData() {          
        let res = JSONfile.d.results.filter(function(val) {
          return (val.FileLeafRef.trim().length > 0);
        }).map(function(obj) {

            return {
              "FileName": obj.FileLeafRef,
              "Path": obj.EncodedAbsUrl,
              "Categories": obj.ResourceType.results.map(function(val) {
                 return val.Label;
              }).join(";")
            };
        });

    // debugger;

      let temp = JSONfile.d.results.filter(function(val) {
        return (val.FileLeafRef.trim().length > 0);
      }).map(function(obj) {

        return obj.ResourceType.results.map(function(val) {
            return val.Label;
          })
        });


      let categories = this.distinctArray(temp).sort();

      $("#km-labels").html(categories.join("<br>"));

      console.log(categories);


  } // ------------- loadData

// ------------------------------------ //

  distinctArray(inp){
    let uniqueArr = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
      if(inp[i] == undefined) continue;
      if(uniqueArr.indexOf(inp[i]) < 0) {
        uniqueArr.push(inp[i]);
      }
    }
    return uniqueArr;
  }
```

#### JSON snippet

```
{
  "d": {
    "results": [
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "id": "[redacted]",
          "uri": "[redacted]",
          ...
          "type": "[redacted]"
        },
        "File": {
          "__metadata": {
            "id": "[redacted]",
            "uri": "[redacted]",
            "type": "SP.File"
          },
          "Name": "[redacted]"
        },
        "FileLeafRef": "[redacted]",
        "ResourceType": {
          "__metadata": {
            "type": "Collection([redacted])"
          },
          "results": [
            {
              "Label": "Guides \uff06 Protocols",
              ...
              ...
            }
          ]
        },
        "EncodedAbsUrl": "[redacted]"
      },
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "id": "[redacted]",
          "uri": "[redacted]",
          ...
          "type": "[redacted]"
        },
        "File": {
          "__metadata": {
            "id": "[redacted]",
            "uri": "[redacted]",
            "type": "[redacted]"
          },
          "Name": "[redacted]"
        },
        "FileLeafRef": "[redacted]",
        "ResourceType": {
          "__metadata": {
            "type": "[redacted]"
          },
          "results": [
            {
              "Label": "Templates",
              "TermGuid": "[redacted]",
              ...
            },
            {
              "Label": "Guides \uff06 Protocols",
              "TermGuid": "[redacted]",
              ...
            }
          ]
        },
        "EncodedAbsUrl": "[redacted]"
      },
...
...
```

#### Update:

```
       let unique = {};
          let temp = JSONfile.d.results.filter(function(val) {
            return (val.FileLeafRef.trim().length > 0);            
          }).forEach(function(obj) {
            obj.ResourceType.results.forEach(function(val) {
              unique[val.Label] = val;
            })
          }).map(function(obj) {

            return obj.ResourceType.results.map(function(val) {
                return val.Label;
              })
            });
```

Comment: `temp` is a 2-dimensional array. `distinctArray()` expects a flat array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an object whose keys are the labels. Since object keys are unique, the values of this object will not have any duplicate labels.

```js
let unique = {};
JSONfile.d.results.filter(function(val) {
  return (val.FileLeafRef.trim().length > 0);
}).forEach(function(obj) {
   obj.ResourceType.results.forEach(function(val) {
     unique[val.Label] = true; // value can be anything, only keys matter
  })
});

let categories = Object.keys(unique).sort();
```

Comment: Would I add it below the second `JSONfile.d.results` section (see post update). If so, I'm getting told that the property of 'map' is undefined.

Comment: I've updated the answer. This replaces all the `.map()` stuff.

Comment: It worked---I moved your code snippet into another block (separate from the update I provided). Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's another way to go, this uses fewer new features.